# SQL average age comparison function returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, function, datetime

So, I'm working in MySQL, writing a function that averages the ages of women and men from a table and compares them, and returns which is greater. Dates are in the format of YYYY-MM-DD, and I'm using DATEDIFF(). The function appears to work correctly, but when I run the script, all I get is a message box with a null value instead of the response it should output.

```
USE tennis;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AverAge;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AverAge()
BEGIN
    DECLARE averWomen DECIMAL(3,2);
    DECLARE averMen DECIMAL(3,2);

    SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE,CURDATE()))
    INTO averWomen
    FROM PLAYERS
    WHERE sex = 'F';

    SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE,CURDATE()))  
    INTO averWomen
    FROM PLAYERS
    WHERE sex = 'M';

    IF averWomen > averMen THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of women is higher. It is ', averWomen) AS message;
    ELSEIF averMen > averWomen THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of women is higher. It is ', averMen) AS message;
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of men and women is equal. It is ', averWomen, ' for women and ', averMen, ' for men.') AS message;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL AverAge();
```

Can someone spot where I'm messing up?

Edit

```
USE tennis;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AverAge;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AverAge()
BEGIN
    DECLARE averWomen DECIMAL(10,6);
    DECLARE averMen DECIMAL(10,6);

    SELECT AVG(EXTRACT(year FROM CURDATE()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BIRTH_DATE))
    INTO averWomen
    FROM PLAYERS
    WHERE SEX = 'F';

    SELECT AVG(EXTRACT(year FROM CURDATE()) - EXTRACT(year FROM BIRTH_DATE))
    INTO averMen
    FROM PLAYERS
    WHERE SEX = 'M';

    IF averWomen > averMen THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of women is higher. It is ', averWomen) AS message;
    ELSEIF averMen > averWomen THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of women is higher. It is ', averMen) AS message;
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT('The average age of men and women is equal. It is ', averWomen, ' for women and ', averMen, ' for men.') AS message;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL AverAge();
```

So, this is what I did that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you declared the variable averMen, you have not initialized it. The query which should be calculating averMen is calculating averWomen instead.

Try changing ...

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE,CURDATE()))  
INTO averWomen
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE sex = 'M';
```

into

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE,CURDATE()))  
INTO averMen
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE sex = 'M';
```

Comment: Gah, I can't believe I missed that. Now I'm just messing up with the averaging for some reason... Though now I'm not getting the expected result, but at least it appears to be running appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is *way* too complicated.  Why not just use conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN avg_f > avg_m
             THEN CONCAT('The average age of women is higher. It is ', avf_f) 
             WHEN avg_m > avg_f
             THEN CONCAT('The average age of men is higher. It is ', avg_m) 
             ELSE CONCAT('The average age of men and women is equal. It is ', avg_f, ' for both.')
        END) AS message
FROM (SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE, CURDATE()) END) as avg_m,
             AVG(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN DATEDIFF(BIRTH_DATE, CURDATE()) END) as avg_f
      FROM PLAYERS
     ) a
```

Why use five queries when you can just use one?

Comment: I'm just learning, but yeah, that would be the much more elegant solution.